# Search in multidimensional array what keys contains a specific value and remove keys that doesn't

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array that contains keywords(email, cart, etc) and each keyword has a specific list of apps(EmailAppA..) with their ranking(1,2..).

```
Array
(
    [email] => Array
        (
            [EmailAppA] => 1
            [EmailAppB] => 2
            [EmailAppC] => 4
        )

    [cart] => Array
        (
            [CartAppA] => 1
            [CartAppB] => 2
            [MyApp] => 4
        )
    [reviews] => Array
        (
            [reviewAppA] => 1
            [reviewAppB] => 4
            [reviewAppC] => 5
            [MyApp] => 7

        )
```

What I want to achieve is to loop in the array, find all keys that contain app 'MyApp' and in final remove keys which don't contain value "MyApp".
The array must remain only with cart and reviews and their values, email was removed.

My code so far, but I am stuck:

```
foreach ($mappedStuff as $keywords=>$value){
    foreach ($value as $apps=>$rank){
        if($apps != 'MyApp'){
          unset($mappedStuff[$keywords];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify `foreach()`

```
foreach ($mappedStuff as $key=>$value){

    if(!in_array('MyApp', array_keys($value))){

      unset($mappedStuff[$key]);

   }

}
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/Z64Um

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the array using [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php). Inside its callback function, you will look for the existence of 'MyApp'. Should it not be existing, the callback function will return false and the current key will therefore be filtered out.

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($apps)
{
   return in_array('MyApp', $apps);
});
```

I just noticed, you want to search for a key existence, not the value, so just change my code to:

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($apps)
{
   return isset($apps['MyApp']);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk`

```
array_walk($a, function($v, $k) use (&$a){
  if(!array_key_exists('MyApp', $v)) unset($a[$k]);
});
```

https://3v4l.org/gtEIt

Answer (score 0):

Use *unset($mappedStuff[$key][$apps])* to remove the value,

```
foreach ($mappedStuff as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $apps => $rank) {
        if($apps == 'MyApp') {
            unset($mappedStuff[$key][$apps]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But here you `unset` the inner element that DO contain (key of) "MyApp"...

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing that you can do is using a `for` loop within a `foreach` to reach your inner values and use `unset` function. For example:

```
//This is your array
foreach($yourArray as $item)
{
    //These are your categories
    for( $i = 0; $i < count($item); $i++ )
    {
        //for every value of your category's keys, check if they don't match 'MyApp'
        if($item[$i] !== "MyApp")
        {
            //If above statement is true, unset them
            unset($item[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Give it a try and tell us :)